# Inotify is not working for etc/passwd

Tags: c++, linux, inotify

I am trying to set listner for passwd file in /etc directory and I am getting notification only for first password change.

```
fd = inotify_init();
wd = inotify_add_watch (fd, "/etc/passwd", IN_MODIFY);
while(1)
{
 read (fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
 struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buff[ i ];
 printf("Event Len -  %d  wd %d \n", event->len, event->wd);
}
```

why it works first time and not later?I Am seeing timestamp change everytime when I change password. Same set of code working fine for some other file.

Comment: Remember that most (if not all) Linux distributions uses [shadow password files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_password), so changing a password may not actually alter `/etc/password`.

Comment: yeah that code wont compile, I just want to give idea what i am trying to do. If i copy the actual code it is so big.

Comment: OK the inode of the file is getting changed. So now I have two options, add watch for /etc directory or remove the previous watch and add watch again for passwd. can any one say which is better option? If I add listner for etc wont it be a overhead? or will it cause for event overflow? In the other case how can i make sure am adding the listner after creating new passwd file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When changing the `/etc/passwd`, most application create a new file and rename it.  This give a new inode number.